# Create a fragment only from java code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on an app where there are several screens and they are only going to be there for one or two clicks by the user. I don't want to create all those screens in XML. So I am looking for a solution where I can create a screen (fragment) temporarily and once the user interacts with it I will just destroy it and show the next screen. So far I am only able to put a button on the activity. Which when clicked a fragment should open. But I am kind of stuck there.

This is my code

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dddddd"));
    relativeLayout.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
    Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());

      button.setText("Launch Activity");
    button.setAllCaps(false);
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dddddd"));
    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
    button.setPadding(4,4,4,4);
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));
    relativeLayout.addView(button);

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
            TextView textView = new     TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText("This a new activity");
            textView.setTextSize(14.2f);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
            textView.setAllCaps(false);
            relativeLayout1.addView(textView);

        }
    });
```

So how to do I do it? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a fragment that has some view, you have to **override onCreateView**

```
       @Nullable
       public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

          //add creating view logic here
          .
          .
          .

          //return view here
          return view;
       }
```

Comment: This makes sense but I am unable to follow here. Can you elaborate exactly how it will be possible?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is possible and XML is an easy way to make UI. Anyway, it would be better to make a new class and implement and extent, so you will make them separately. 
If you are going to use Fragment, you have to implement "onCreateView".